# Scheme - how to not 'flattened' pairs in list?

Tags: scheme, flatten

My task is to get first atom in structure, that's why I'm used flatten and func "first-atom-lst". But there is one big problem - I need to handle pairs in structure and do NOT broke pairs. Can you please help me to handle this?

```
(define (check-improper? lst)
  (cond
       ((null? lst) #f)
       ((number? lst) #f)
       ((atom? lst) #f)
       ((list? lst) #f)
  ((pair? (cdr lst)) #t)
  (#t #f)
  ))

(define (improper-to-proper lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) '())
    ((not (pair? (cdr lst))) (cons lst  '()))
    (else (cons (car lst) (improper-to-proper (cdr lst))))
    )
  )

(define (first-atom-from-pair lst)
  (cond ((check-improper? lst))
        ((null? lst) #f)
        ((atom? (car (flatten lst)))         
         (car (flatten lst)))                
        (else                      
         (first-atom (cdr (flatten lst)))))) 

(define (first-atom lst)
  (cond ((check-improper? lst))
        ((null? lst) #f)
        ((atom? lst) lst)
        ((pair? (cdr lst)) (first-atom-from-pair lst))
        ((pair? lst) #f)
        ((atom? (car (flatten (not pair? lst))))         
         (car (flatten (not pair? lst))))                
        (else                      
         (first-atom (cdr (flatten lst))))))
```

Comment: show inputs and expected outputs

Comment: What are broke pairs?

Comment: for example - input: ((2 . 0) 2)
Expected output: 2

input: ((1 . 0) (2 . 3) 2)
output: 2

input: ((2 . 1) (2 3) 1)
outpit: 2

Comment: @Artem is your question *how to get the first atom in any list that contains proper and improper sublists*, or is it *how to get the first atom in a list such that all the sublists from the input to the atom are themselves "proper"*? Ie. in an input of '((1 . 0) 3), would the output be 1 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot flatten improper lists, but it's actually overkill in your case anyway. You could do something like this:

```
(define (first-atom tree)
  (if (null? tree)
      #f
      (if (pair? tree)
          (first-atom (car tree))
          tree)))
```

then

```
> (first-atom '((2 . 0) 2))
2
> (first-atom '((1 . 0) (2 . 3) 2))
1
> (first-atom '((2 . 1) (2 3) 1))
2
> (first-atom '(((((((1 . 2) 3) 4))))))
1
```

Note that my second result differs from yours, but I believe mine is correct since the first element of a flattened list would also yield 1.

Answer (score 0):

Solve problem, but need improvement.

```
(define (atom? a)
  (and (not (pair? a))
       (not (null? a))))

(define (true-pair? p)
  (cond
    ((list? p) #f)
    ((pair? (cdr p)) #f)
    (else #t)))

(define (flatten-atom x)
  (cond ((null? x) '())
        ((atom? x) (list x))
        ((true-pair? x) (list x))
        (else (append (flatten-atom (car x))
                      (flatten-atom (cdr x))))))

(flatten-atom '((a b . c)))
(flatten-atom '((a b c) d e () ((f)) (1 . 2)))
(flatten-atom '((a b . c) (((4 5))) () 6 (7 . 8)))

> (a (b . c))
> (a b c d e f (1 . 2))
> (a (b . c) 4 5 6 (7 . 8))
```